# design pattern like electricity switch?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, software-design

I'm coding in c# and currently implementing an "electricity switch"  like component.

General idea is there are a bunch of classes implementing a ISwitch interface, and when one is false it basically triggers an Off() action and when all are true then On().

Idea is pretty clear and I'm pretty sure there is a design pattern for such behavior / functionality, would appreciate a reference to documentation so I can educate myself and look at best practices,

cheers

Comment: Consider looking at the Observer pattern. [link](https://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns)

Comment: @Stucky thanks, will have a look at it! From first glance, it looks like notifying all observers is a bit of an overhead to what I need, I would basically want to know at a given time the On / Off state of the circuit, so I'm not sure I would need to notify all, just to the "Main Controller" if i can put it this way

Comment: Create a Manager class, add the switches in a `List<ISwitch>` and have a `public bool On => _switches.All(x => x.On)` and a reverse Off?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks for your response, I found the answer below helpful. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
public delegate void HandleSwitchStateChanged(ISwitch source, bool switchedOn);

public interface ISwitch
{
    event HandleSwitchStateChanged SwitchStateChanged;
    bool SwitchedOn { get; }
}

public enum SwitchesState
{
    AllOn,
    AllOff,
    Mixed
}

public class MonitorsMultipleSwitches
{
    private readonly ISwitch[] _switches;
    private SwitchesState _switchesState;

    public MonitorsMultipleSwitches(ISwitch[] switches)
    {
        _switches = switches;

        foreach (var item in switches)
        {
            item.SwitchStateChanged += HandleSwitchStateChanged;
        }
    }

    public void HandleSwitchStateChanged(ISwitch source, bool switchedOn)
    {
        SwitchesState newState;
        if (_switches.All(s => s.SwitchedOn))
            newState = SwitchesState.AllOn;
        else if (_switches.All(s => !s.SwitchedOn))
            newState = SwitchesState.AllOff;
        else
            newState = SwitchesState.Mixed;

        if (newState == _switchesState) return; // no meaningful change
        _switchesState = newState;

        // do something.
    }
}
```

In this example one class is monitoring multiple switches. If the state of any of them changes it checks to see if all are on, all are off, or some are on and some are off. Then, if that's different from the state it was previously in, it can react as needed.

(Perhaps `AllOff` isn't a state you care about - either they're all on or you don't care.)

Comment: Nice! thanks for that! did not think on event based implementation